# Only booting to GRUB automatically

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, grub, elementary-os

I installed Elementary OS earlier as the sole OS on my machine.

When I boot now, GRUB is displayed on the screen (with a message about minimal bash being available).

I can boot to Elementary OS by typing the following command:

`configfile (hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

and then selecting "Linux".

Is there a way to automate this, so that when I turn my machine on, Elementary OS is opened automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Run `update-grub` (as root) or `sudo update-grub` (as a normal user) after you boot Elementary OS and login.

This will generate the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, including boot menu, and default with timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using the following command:

```
sudo cp /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi /boot/efi/EFI/grub/grubx64.efi
```